# Beautiful Soup and Python scraping - unable to reference the correct element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I took a pre made script for scraping values I was seeking off of craigstlist - and wanted to expand on this and scrape data from other forums (for example Pinkbike).

Original Script that works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import time
#from config import *

Free_CL_URL = "https://philadelphia.craigslist.org/d/bicycles/search/bia"


def crawlFree(pageval):
    # crawls the free items section and parses HTML
    if pageval == 0:
        r = requests.get(Free_CL_URL).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    else:
        r = requests.get(Free_CL_URL + "?s=" + str(pageval)).text
        time.sleep(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def searchItems(input):
    # in each page crawled from crawlFree , extract the titles, lower the character case and compare against search strings to append a result list
    itemlist = []
    for i in input:
        TitleSplit = str(i.contents[0]).split()
        TitleSplit = str([TitleSplit.lower() for TitleSplit in TitleSplit])

        if "cyclocross" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])
        elif "58" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])
        elif "cx" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])

    return itemlist

pageval = 0
totalist = []

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    soup = crawlFree(pageval)
    # crawl page until you hit a page with the following text, signifing the end of the catagory
    if "search and you will find" and "the harvest moon wanes" in soup.text:
        print("\nEnd of Script")
        break
    else:
        print("\nSearching page " + str((int(pageval / 120))))
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk")
        itemlist = searchItems(links)
        totalist.append(itemlist)

        pageval += 120

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

# message compliation and delivery
message = "Subject:CL Free Bot Report - " + str(len(totalist)) + "\n\n"

for i in totalist:
    for i in i:
        message += str("\n" + str(i) + "\n")


print(message)
```

The issue that I am stuck with right now is this bit here:

```
print("\nSearching page " + str((int(pageval / 120))))
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_="result-title hdrlnk")
        itemlist = searchItems(links)
        totalist.append(itemlist)
```

the links variable an pulling the a href doesnt seem to translate very well to pinkbike.

[image: Please see element that has been inspected]

but when I try to pull this value:

```
        print("\nSearching page " + str((int(pageval / 120))))
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_="href")
        itemlist = searchItems(links)
        totalist.append(itemlist)
```

I seem to not be scraping this value - but cant seem to understand why.
Tried a few different ways of formatting this but falling flat.

Full code of why I am trying is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import time
#from config import *

URL = "https://www.pinkbike.com/buysell/list/?category=77"


def crawlFree(pageval):
    # crawls our results from the url above
    if pageval == 0:
        r = requests.get(URL).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    else:
        r = requests.get(URL + "?s=" + str(pageval)).text
        time.sleep(1)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def searchItems(input):
    # in each page crawled from crawlFree , extract the titles, lower the character case and compare against search strings to append a result list
    itemlist = []
    for i in input:
        TitleSplit = str(i.contents[0]).split()
        TitleSplit = str([TitleSplit.lower() for TitleSplit in TitleSplit])

        if "cyclocross" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])
        elif "58" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])
        elif "large" in TitleSplit:
            print(str("\n" + i.contents[0]))
            itemlist.append(i.contents[0])
            print((i.attrs['href']))
            itemlist.append(i.attrs['href'])

    return itemlist

pageval = 0
totalist = []

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    soup = crawlFree(pageval)
    # crawl page until you hit a page with the following text, signifing the end of the catagory
    if "search and you will find" and "the harvest moon wanes" in soup.text:
        print("\nEnd of Script")
        break
    else:
        print("\nSearching page " + str((int(pageval / 120))))
        links = soup.find_all('a', class_="href")
        itemlist = searchItems(links)
        totalist.append(itemlist)

        pageval += 120

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

# message compliation and delivery
message = "Subject:CL Free Bot Report - " + str(len(totalist)) + "\n\n"

for i in totalist:
    for i in i:
        message += str("\n" + str(i) + "\n")


print(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of reputation, I am not able to comment directly.

**Following will work for your else clause**

```
links = [div.find_all('a')[1] for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='bsitem')]
```

**But ...**
You have to do a little bit more, cause in scraping there is no one fits it all solution. So you have also to deal with jumping to the next page...

There are only 20 not 120 bikes per page and the parameter is not `s` it is `page`

Hope this hint helps you, let us know.

Comment: Nice - I see what you did there.
I see what the issue was - its a div class and not a href.

Now I need to start looking at what you suggested - how do we turn the page!
Thank you!

Comment: I was able to get this sorted.
```